# Taylor formula question

Tags: calculus

Use Taylor's Formula to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x \sin(x)-x(1+x)}{x^2}$$

I used l'Hôpital's rule to find that this limit is zero, but I don't know how to use Taylor's Formula to evaluate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Start by using $\displaystyle e^x\sin x=(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots)(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots)$

Comment: To give an extra little hint, you don't actually need to expand very much of this product to figure it out.

Comment: I understand you are using the Taylor series to get that result, am I correct?so I can rewrite as $e^x sin(x)= (1+x^n/n!)(x-x^3/3!+....)$, what should I do next, can you give me further hint, i don't understand this chapter very well.

Comment: Now you want to multiply these two series together (just as you would polynomials), subtract $x(1+x)$, then divide by $x^2$ and take the limit.  As @dfeuer points out, you only need to multiply out the series up to degree 3.

Answer (score 0):

First, we recall that if $f^{(j)}(0)=0$, for every $0<j<k-1$ and $f^{(k)}(0)\neq 0$, the Taylor series expansion of order $k$ on a neighborhood of $0$ has the meaningful formula
$$ f(x)=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k+r_k(x),$$
with $r_k(x)=\frac{f^{(k+1)}(tx)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}$ ($0<t<1$).

In concrete, for the function $$f(x)=e^{x}\sin(x)-x(x+1)$$ it is straightforward to see that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(0)=2\neq 0$. From this condition, one get that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^3+r_3(x)$$
in a neighborhood of $0$.

By inserting the above Taylor series expansion of order $3$ on the limit, one easily conclude that 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{x}\sin(x)-x(x+1)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{3}x+ \frac{r_3(x)}{x^2}\right)=0.$$